# Issue with Let's Encrypt certificate: https://www.example.com not working with redirection to https://example.com

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, certificate, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have an issue with the certificate that I have generated for a website (dubbed here `example.com`).

I can type in browser `http://www.example.com` and successfully redirected to `https://example.com` as I wanted (with a certificate generated by `let's encrypt`). I have done this redirection with Rewrite Rules with Apache2. The redirection to `https://example.com` also works fine when I type `http://example.com`.

Now, I am face to an issue when I type directly in browser `https://wwww.example.com`: I get the following error:

[image]

To generate let's encrypt certificate, I have executed the following command:

`./certbot-auto certonly --no-bootstrap --no-self-upgrade --renew-by-default -a standalone -d example.com --rsa-key-size 4096`

I would like to generate a certificate working both for `example.com` and `www.example.com`: is the command above with `cerbot-auto` correct for this?

It seems that before my migration from Debian 7 to Debian 10, I had a `*.example.com` name in the certificate info window of the browser but I am not sure.

How to type `https://www.example.com` and to be correctly redirected to `https://example.com` without having the error illustrated in the figure above?

### Update 1

Is a single certificate sufficient to make all the redirections to be performed, I mean in my case only one certificate `example.com`? This was the case on my previous OS, I think that I had only a unique certificate (for `example.com`).

I want to  have the following redirections:

```
http://example.com -----> https://example.com

http://www.example.com -----> https://example.com

https://www.example.com -----> https://example.com
```

except for URL containing the directory `podcast` where I want to stay in HTTP mode.

So, from [Ref: Apache redirect www to non-www and HTTP to HTTPS](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-apache/), I did:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/podcast [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Does these Rewrite rules seem to be correct?

Unfortunately, if I type directly `https://www.example.com`, I am not redirected to `https://example.com` and the Warning window figure above appears, I don't know what to do.

### Update 2

**1)** Does Let's Encrypt offer the possibility to generate a "wildcards" certificate ?, I mean under the form `*.example.com` when we look at the certificate in browsers.

**2)** Moreover, Does anyone know how to perform with Apache2 Rewrite rules the rule which allows to redirect `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`.

To get more information, I am starting a bounty.
At the end of the bounty, I talk about what to do to make a redirection from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` (these URL are masked into bounty under the same href tag but they are different).

### Update 3

I think my issue is not about wildcards certificates since I just want a redirection from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` (**don't take into account of the UPDATE 2 above**. Surely a simple rewrite rule should be enough. Before my current OS (Debian 10), I was running well all my config files that I try to use again now. Especially, I was using only one certificate generated with the option "`-d example.com`" (I didn't use a second domain "`www.example.com`").

I am going to try to modify these rewrite rules to get this redirection without being obliged to generate a `www.example.com` certificate files.

Comment: Add another option `-d www.website.com` when running `certbot-auto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try running this minor update to your original certbot-auto command to get your certificate to include the additional `www.example.com` domain name
(I believe this is what John Hanley was talking about in his comment on your original question)
Please note, according to one source (letsencrypt community link below) you may have to remove URL rewrite rules if you already have them set up, before the certification process will work. (if you run the command and get an error, that might be why)

```
./certbot-auto certonly --no-bootstrap --no-self-upgrade --renew-by-default -a standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com --rsa-key-size 4096
```

references that might be helpful:

command paramter reference for certbot (man page)
https://certbot.eff.org/docs/man/certbot.html?highlight=bootstrap

letsencrypt community discussion of adding a new domain
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/add-a-domain-using-certbot-auto/33660

letsencrypt documentation for updating an existing certificate
https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#re-creating-and-updating-existing-certificates
note, according to the man page, --renew-by-default implies --expand, which is used in these examples
(--expand just prevents you from having to answer whether you are intentionally updating the existing certificate)

I think your rewrite rule looks mostly fine as it is, as mentioned before it might need to be removed temporarily to get you certificate generated. And you may need "RewriteEngine On" before those rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/podcast [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

And to the question about wildcard certificates, they are supported but only with the help of additional plugins. See more here:
https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html?highlight=wildcard#id14

Answer (score 0):

LetsEncrypt offers wildcard certificates in order to do `*.example.com` however they can only be issued via DNS-01 level challenges.

You're using HTTP validation, where a specific file is uploaded to prove ownership, however this is insufficient for proving that you have ownership of an entire domain.

Certbot has limited support for being able to issue wildcard certs automatically, but [this](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianbuster-nginx) may be of use to you if you scroll to the wildcard section. It's limited in terms of which OS + Server + DNS provider that you have. Basically you need to be able to automatically create and modify DNS TXT records with your registrar.

I've found that using the [acme.sh](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh) project to issue wildcard certs is much more flexible and works with more DNS providers, although it's a bit more of a manual process.

If your main DNS provider for your domain isn't supported, you can look into "alias mode" where you can use a subdomain or other domain on another DNS provider that is supported to act as your proxy-domain for validating that you own your main domain.