# CGI scripts no more available after fixing a https://www redirection

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting, cgi

I make following the post [https://www to https://no-www redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268984/issue-with-lets-encrypt-certificate-https-www-website-com-not-working-with).

I have finally managed to generate a wildcard certificate `*.website.com` which allows me with rewrite rules to get redirection to https://website.com from initially https://www.website.com.

Now, I am faced to another issue: my `CGI` scripts in `cgi-bin` directory are not working anymore like for example: https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl

I am using the following rewrite rules to get `https://www.website.com` to `https://webiste.com` (using zope framework behind apache) :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    # Name
    ServerAdmin admin@website.com
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com

    # LOG
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    # ACTIVATE SSL
    SSLEngine On

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/chain.pem

    # REWRITE
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/awstats [NC]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]

    SSLProxyEngine On
    RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
    #CacheDisable *

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

    Alias /awstatsclasses "/usr/share/awstats/lib/"
    Alias /awstats-icon "/usr/share/awstats/icon/"
    Alias /awstatscss "/usr/share/doc/awstats/examples/css"

<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@website.com
    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/www\. [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/podcast [NC]
    # Rewrite below works : redirect 80 => https
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    # For Zope
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)  http://localhost:9674/++vh++http:%{SERVER_NAME}:80/++/$1 [P,L]

</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

It's pretty tricky but the result is that if I type : `https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl`, I get the equivalent of a 404 error of Apache2 but coming from Zope.

How to make work my CGI scripts again ?

It's frustrating from previous post : I have fixed the redirection https://www.website.com to https://website.com but right now, these are the CGI scripts which are no longer accessible.

Before the modifications about the redirection https://www to https://no-www, the scripts were available. I don't understand where it could come from.

### Update 1

Output of Apache2:

```
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.445944 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9866] ssl_engine_kernel.c(383): [client 91.171.129.151:7825] AH02034: Subsequent (No.7) HTTPS request received for child 7 (server website.com:443), referer: https://website.com/style/style2.css
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.445986 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9866] mod_authz_core.c(846): [client 91.171.129.151:7825] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives), referer: https://website.com/style/style2.css
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.446022 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9866] mod_proxy.c(1249): [client 91.171.129.151:7825] AH01143: Running scheme https handler (attempt 0), referer: https://website.com/style/style2.css
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.446032 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9866] proxy_util.c(2316): AH00942: HTTPS: has acquired connection for (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.446041 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9866] proxy_util.c(2369): [client 91.171.129.151:7825] AH00944: connecting https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:website.com:443/++/images/up-arrow.png to localhost:8443, referer: https://website.com/style/style2.css
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.446204 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9866] proxy_util.c(2578): [client 91.171.129.151:7825] AH00947: connected /++vh++https:website.com:443/++/images/up-arrow.png to localhost:8443, referer: https://website.com/style/style2.css
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.446288 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9866] proxy_util.c(3047): AH02824: HTTPS: connection established with 127.0.0.1:8443 (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.446307 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9866] proxy_util.c(3215): AH00962: HTTPS: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:8443 (localhost)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.446320 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9866] [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.454637 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9865] proxy_util.c(2331): AH00943: *: has released connection for (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.454721 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9865] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02001: Connection closed to child 0 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.454772 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9865] proxy_util.c(3154): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02642: proxy: connection shutdown
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.459030 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9851] proxy_util.c(2331): AH00943: *: has released connection for (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.459109 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9851] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02001: Connection closed to child 0 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.459144 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9866] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1740): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 0, CRL checking mode: none (0) [subject: CN=website.com / issuer: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US / serial: 033E19116893A728CDC809BA511D98069F7E / notbefore: Jun 29 23:22:00 2017 GMT / notafter: Sep 27 23:22:00 2017 GMT]
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.459161 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9851] proxy_util.c(3154): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02642: proxy: connection shutdown
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.459193 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9866] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1740): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 0, CRL checking mode: none (0) [subject: CN=website.com / issuer: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US / serial: 033E19116893A728CDC809BA511D98069F7E / notbefore: Jun 29 23:22:00 2017 GMT / notafter: Sep 27 23:22:00 2017 GMT]
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.463339 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9866] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2235): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1, Cipher: AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.463411 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9853] proxy_util.c(2331): AH00943: *: has released connection for (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.463486 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9853] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02001: Connection closed to child 0 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.463534 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9853] proxy_util.c(3154): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02642: proxy: connection shutdown
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.471527 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9866] proxy_util.c(2331): AH00943: *: has released connection for (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.471590 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9866] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02001: Connection closed to child 0 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.471627 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9866] proxy_util.c(3154): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02642: proxy: connection shutdown
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.511179 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9853] ssl_engine_kernel.c(383): [client 91.171.129.151:7821] AH02034: Subsequent (No.8) HTTPS request received for child 4 (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.511249 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9853] mod_authz_core.c(846): [client 91.171.129.151:7821] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.511303 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9853] mod_proxy.c(1249): [client 91.171.129.151:7821] AH01143: Running scheme https handler (attempt 0)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.511332 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9853] proxy_util.c(2316): AH00942: HTTPS: has acquired connection for (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.511343 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9853] proxy_util.c(2369): [client 91.171.129.151:7821] AH00944: connecting https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:website.com:443/++/favicon.ico to localhost:8443
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.511551 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9853] proxy_util.c(2578): [client 91.171.129.151:7821] AH00947: connected /++vh++https:website.com:443/++/favicon.ico to localhost:8443
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.511670 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9853] proxy_util.c(3047): AH02824: HTTPS: connection established with 127.0.0.1:8443 (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.511696 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9853] proxy_util.c(3215): AH00962: HTTPS: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:8443 (localhost)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.511713 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9853] [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.512494 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9853] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1740): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 0, CRL checking mode: none (0) [subject: CN=website.com / issuer: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US / serial: 033E19116893A728CDC809BA511D98069F7E / notbefore: Jun 29 23:22:00 2017 GMT / notafter: Sep 27 23:22:00 2017 GMT]
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.512541 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9853] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1740): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 0, CRL checking mode: none (0) [subject: CN=website.com / issuer: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US / serial: 033E19116893A728CDC809BA511D98069F7E / notbefore: Jun 29 23:22:00 2017 GMT / notafter: Sep 27 23:22:00 2017 GMT]
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.517345 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9853] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2235): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1, Cipher: AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.525382 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9853] proxy_util.c(2331): AH00943: *: has released connection for (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.525443 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9853] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02001: Connection closed to child 0 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:33.525476 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9853] proxy_util.c(3154): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02642: proxy: connection shutdown
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:34.109743 2020] [watchdog:debug] [pid 9869] mod_watchdog.c(567): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:34.109885 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9869] proxy_util.c(1924): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:34.109901 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9869] proxy_util.c(1981): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:34.109955 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9869] proxy_util.c(2032): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 9869 for (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:34.110492 2020] [watchdog:debug] [pid 9870] mod_watchdog.c(567): AH02980: Watchdog: nothing configured?
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:34.110610 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9870] proxy_util.c(1924): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:34.110625 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9870] proxy_util.c(1981): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:34.110674 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9870] proxy_util.c(2032): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 9870 for (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:48.437276 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9864] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [client 91.171.129.151:7823] AH02001: Connection closed to child 5 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:48.438985 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9849] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [client 91.171.129.151:7822] AH02001: Connection closed to child 0 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:48.467248 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9865] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [client 91.171.129.151:7824] AH02001: Connection closed to child 6 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:48.470814 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9851] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [client 91.171.129.151:7820] AH02001: Connection closed to child 2 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:48.478015 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9866] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [client 91.171.129.151:7825] AH02001: Connection closed to child 7 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:48.539212 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9853] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [client 91.171.129.151:7821] AH02001: Connection closed to child 4 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.282123 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9852] [client 127.0.0.1:49482] AH01964: Connection to child 3 established (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.282356 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9852] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2319): [client 127.0.0.1:49482] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername website.com found
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.282407 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9852] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2319): [client 127.0.0.1:49482] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername website.com found
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.282418 2020] [core:debug] [pid 9852] protocol.c(2314): [client 127.0.0.1:49482] AH03155: select protocol from , choices=h2,http/1.1 for server website.com
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.296616 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9852] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2235): [client 127.0.0.1:49482] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.296936 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9852] ssl_engine_kernel.c(383): [client 127.0.0.1:49482] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 3 (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.297023 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9852] mod_authz_core.c(846): [client 127.0.0.1:49482] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.297087 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9852] mod_proxy.c(1249): [client 127.0.0.1:49482] AH01143: Running scheme https handler (attempt 0)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.297101 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9852] proxy_util.c(2316): AH00942: HTTPS: has acquired connection for (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.297113 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9852] proxy_util.c(2369): [client 127.0.0.1:49482] AH00944: connecting https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:website.com:443/++/index.html to localhost:8443
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.297467 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9852] proxy_util.c(2578): [client 127.0.0.1:49482] AH00947: connected /++vh++https:website.com:443/++/index.html to localhost:8443
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.297696 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9852] proxy_util.c(3047): AH02824: HTTPS: connection established with 127.0.0.1:8443 (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.297722 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9852] proxy_util.c(3215): AH00962: HTTPS: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:8443 (localhost)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.297739 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 9852] [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.298590 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9852] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1740): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 0, CRL checking mode: none (0) [subject: CN=website.com / issuer: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US / serial: 033E19116893A728CDC809BA511D98069F7E / notbefore: Jun 29 23:22:00 2017 GMT / notafter: Sep 27 23:22:00 2017 GMT]
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.298625 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9852] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1740): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02275: Certificate Verification, depth 0, CRL checking mode: none (0) [subject: CN=website.com / issuer: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US / serial: 033E19116893A728CDC809BA511D98069F7E / notbefore: Jun 29 23:22:00 2017 GMT / notafter: Sep 27 23:22:00 2017 GMT]
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.303513 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9852] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2235): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1, Cipher: AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.312046 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9852] proxy_util.c(2331): AH00943: *: has released connection for (*)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.312139 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9852] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02001: Connection closed to child 0 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443)
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.312204 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 9852] proxy_util.c(3154): [remote 127.0.0.1:8443] AH02642: proxy: connection shutdown
[Sun Mar 01 10:49:56.312461 2020] [ssl:debug] [pid 9852] ssl_engine_io.c(1106): [client 127.0.0.1:49482] AH02001: Connection closed to child 3 with standard shutdown (server website.com:443):%s/do
```

And output of Zope:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2020:10:49:01 +0200] "GET /++vh++https:www.website.com:443/++/cgi-bin/awstats.pl HTTP/1.1" 404 102 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0"
```

### Update 2

Some interesting results to fix my issue:

**If I do: 1)**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

...

# REWRITE
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/awstats [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]

...
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, the redirection from https://www to https:// is well achieved but `CGI` scripts generates a Zope error.

**If I do: 2)** remove the line:

```
 `RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]` )
```

i.e :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

...

# REWRITE
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/awstats [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]

...
</VirtualHost>
```

Then the redirection from https://www to https:// is not achieved but `CGI` scripts are available by typing in browser `https://website.com/cgi-bin/awstats.pl`.

How could I combine these 2 different configurations in order to have in the same time redirection and `CGI` scripts available ?

Comment: What do you see in the apache's error.log file? Maybe the one you're using for zope is doing this. I am sure its hard to fix

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about programming at all.  Questions about web server configuration are more appropriate, and are more likely to get answers, on StackExchange's [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing in your workarounds is that the RewriteCond's only associate with the single RewriteRule that immediately follows.

If you want to skip the redirect to zope when the CGI is requested, exclude that particular RewriteRule by preceding it with a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/awstats
# existing rule from Question
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: Great , it works ! I didn't know about the single rewriterule whis has to follow immediatly the rewrite cond. Regards