# Redirect https://www.website.com to https://website.com not working

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I make following post on redirection of `https://www.website.com` to `https://website.com` :

[Issue with Let's Encrypt certificate : https://www.website.com not working with redirection to https://website.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268984/issue-with-lets-encrypt-certificate-https-www-website-com-not-working-with)

I can't get to  achieve this redirection and I don't understand what is the reason.

If I type `https://www.website.com`, it remains on `https://www.website.com` and doesn't perform the redirection to `https://website.com`.

My config is a little special with a Zope server working with Apache2.

For the moment, here below are my rewrite rules (`http://www.website.com` and `http//website.com` are both redirected fine to `https://website.com`) :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    # REWRITE to get https://www.website.com to https://website.com except for cgi-bin scripts
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/search [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/awstats [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# www to non www for HTTP and HTTPS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/podcast [NC]
# Rewrite below works : redirect 80 => https
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/(.*)  http://localhost:9674/++vh++http:%{SERVER_NAME}:80/++/$1 [P,L]

</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are [few things of note](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> 1. One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The following rule is then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its pattern, and if these conditions are met.
> 2. The RewriteRule directive......can occur more than once, with each instance defining a single rewrite rule. The order in which these rules are defined is important - this is the order in which they will be applied at run-time.
> 3. In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html"). This is the (%-decoded) URL-path.
> 4. If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

You also make use of [L|last](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) flags, which makes the engine stop processing further rules after `RewriteRule` is run.

The above sorta gives you an idea how the engine runs your rewrites:

1. `RewriteRules` are processed sequentially (unless you specify `L` flag, which you do for all rules)
2. Each `RewriteRule` can have many `RewriteCond` which all must match before `RewriteRule` is considered. It also means that `RewriteCond` must be repeated for each `RewriteRule` individually (there's however an [interesting technique](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s) to group RewriteRules into if-then-else blocks)
3. In your case (`VirtualHost` context), only the URL-paths are matched by default unless you manually match `HTTP_HOST` variable.

With this in mind, I see a few issues with your rewrite rules (I swapped http and https vhosts around for readability but it does not matter):

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80> <!-- your http:// requests will end up with this block, because 80 is the port for http -->
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # www to non www for HTTP and HTTPS <!-- I believe HTTPS traffic is NOT handled by this vhost at all, it arrives straight to *:443 queue -->
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/www\. [NC,OR] <!-- you evaluate path component of your request uri to begin with "www." (i.e. /www.index.html) - this will obviously never match, you however have OR flag, which proceeds to the second condition -->
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/podcast [NC] <!-- you check if the path does not start with "/podcast" - this is easy to test - try http://www.website.com/podcast and see if you get redirected to HTTPS - I suspect you will not -->
    # Rewrite below works : redirect 80 => https <!-- I suspect it works by accident, please test it out with http://www.website.com/podcast to confirm my theory -->
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L] <!-- we end up here, and regardless of the requested path we issue a 301 redirect to https version of the website. This is marked as Last rule, so the engine should stop processing here -->
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)  http://localhost:9674/++vh++http:%{SERVER_NAME}:80/++/$1 [P,L] <!-- this I believe kicks in when you request a "/podcast" path - this will proxy the request to your http://localhost:9674/ -->
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443><!-- this is where your 301 redirect will com after bouncing through first set of rules above -->
    # REWRITE to get https://www.website.com to https://website.com except for cgi-bin scripts
    RewriteEngine On <!-- this is important, keep it on -->
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/search [NC] <!-- you check whether url path does not contain /cgi-bin/search -->
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/awstats [NC]<!-- AND does not contain /cgi-bin/awstats-->
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]<!-- if both conditions above are met - proxy the request to backend and stop further processing. -->
</VirtualHost>
```

As far as I see - there's no rule to rewrite `https://www.website.com -> https://website.com`, the only bit your https rewrite is checking is `/cgi-bin`

My suggestion would be along the following lines (it's probably not a copy and paste solution, but hopefully you will have gotten the gist):

```xml
<VirtualHost *:443>    
    RewriteEngine On
    # www to non www for HTTPS
    <!-- checking for the same thing again -->
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L] <!-- some people might argue second redirect here is excessive since you already arrived at correct host, but I'd leave this for you to sort out -->
    <!-- your /cgi-bin checks can be merged into one regex --> 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/(search|awstats) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://localhost:8443/++vh++https:%{SERVER_NAME}:443/++/$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # www to non www for HTTP
    <!-- if you want to keep your `/podcast` on http check it first -->
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/podcast [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)  http://localhost:9674/++vh++http:%{SERVER_NAME}:80/++/$1 [P,L]
    <!-- everything else will get redirected to https -->
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for only one website of many that were virtually hosted on a amazon lightsail bitnami implementation.

After commenting out the line

```
ServerName mywebsite.com:80
```

In the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf file the problem was sovled.